Umbraco 13 distributed cache is not updated
I am running Umbraco 13.3.2 in Azure with the following configurations based on https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/v/13.latest-lts/fundamentals/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/azure-web-apps
Admin instance:

MainDomLock = FileSystemMainDomLock
LocalTempStorageLocation = EnvironmentTemp
LuceneDirectoryFactory = SyncedTempFileSystemDirectoryFactory

Public instance:

MainDomLock = FileSystemMainDomLock
LocalTempStorageLocation = EnvironmentTemp
LuceneDirectoryFactory = TempFileSystemDirectoryFactory

The issue I am facing is content just disappears. Content tabs are missing and fields that did contain values are now empty.
A restart of the Azure App Services restores the data but clearly this isn't ideal.
The logs indicate the following:
Error Log 1
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Lock request time out period exceeded.
Error Log 2
Umbraco.Cms.Core.DistributedLocking.Exceptions.DistributedWriteLockTimeoutException: Failed to acquire write lock for id: -331.
Error Log 3
DISTRIBUTED CACHE IS NOT UPDATED
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction (Process ID 83) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.
Error Log 4
System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
And then the subsequent errors are all related to the missing content.
The errors would suggest an issue with the load balancing but as far as I'm aware the setup is correct based on the documentation.
Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?
